# android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException on released apk app

Tags: android, ant

I know this is not the first time this question is asked but I tried all the things that's supposed to be the solution but to no avail.

1. delete  gen/bin folder
2. clean
3. layout does not exist ( it does, it's in my res/layout folder )
4. not using android.R
5. i forgot the rest but you get the picture...

Here's the situation.

I have an android app that when in debug mode, works fine but when I create the release apk via ant, throws and exception `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03004a` when i attempt to start it after installing the apk generate by the ant build. this wasn't happening before i added the android facebook3.5 sdk.

When i do the release, i usually just enter:

`ant release-all`

The build.xml that corresponds to that is shown below ( snippet):

```
<target name="release-all">
    <record name="logfile.txt" action="start" append="false" />
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${antcontrib.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <for list="${unis}" param="uni">
        <sequential>
            <echo>Number @{uni}</echo>
            <var name="university.name" value="@{uni}"/>
            <echo>Building University Name ${university.name}</echo>
            <subant
                buildpath="build.xml"
                failonerror="true">
                <target name="clean" />
                <target name="release" />
            </subant>
            <echo>--------</echo>
            <echo>Copying files to dropbox</echo>
            <copy todir="${dropbox.dir}/<somepaththatiwillnotspecify>">
                <fileset dir="${out.absolute.dir}">
                    <include name="*release.apk"/>
                </fileset>
                <mapper type="glob" from="*release.apk" to="@{uni}.apk"/>
            </copy>
            <var name="university.name" unset="true"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <record name="logfile.txt" action="stop"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been stuck with this for days but finally found the solution. i have a target defined in my build.xml ( see below )

```
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
     <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="package" />
        <arg value="-f" />
        <arg value="--auto-add-overlay" />
        <arg value="-M" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/${android.library.reference.1}/res"/>
        <arg value="-A" />
        <arg path="${asset.absolute.dir}" />
        <arg value="-I" />
        <arg path="${android.jar}" />
        <arg value="-F" />
        <arg path="${out.absolute.dir}/${resource.package.file.name}" />
        <arg value="--rename-manifest-package" />
        <arg value="pokit.campus.${university.name}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

the `${basedir}/${android.library.reference.1}/res` and the one before it `-S` was commented. I just uncommented it and the thing worked. I'm not really sure about the why but I thought it was logical to uncomment since I have recently added the facebook-sdk library which as you know this error was non-existent before using the facebook-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking settings in your proguard.cfg.  I normally get this when proguard obfuscates stuff and it includes items that should not have been included.  Maybe you can try these settings:

-dontwarn com.somenameoflibrary.**
-keep class somenameoflibary.** { *; }

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. went even as far as disabling proguard but the exception still occurrs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case neither Project->Clean nor ant clean worked. Issue was fixed after I deselected jdk and selected jre under Preferences ->Installed JREs